# How do I add pagination to this static blog list page on NextJS? (It uses markdown files as blogs)

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, pagination, metadata

I am using nextjs to build a static blog generated from markdown files. I have a function getPostMetadata that gets the data from my "test" folder which holds my markdown files. How do I dynamically add pagination to this blog list? It pulls metadata from markdown files. I tried using this [tutorial](https://fabiancdng.com/blog/pagination-in-next-js-using-ssg) but I couldn't make it work for my metadata.

My getPostMetadata component looks like this:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";

export interface PostMetadata {
    slug: string
    data: any
}

const getPostMetadata = (path: string, currentPage: number, postsPerPage: number): PostMetadata[] => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
  const markdownPosts = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".md"));
  
  // Calculate the starting index for slicing the posts array
  const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * postsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + postsPerPage;

  // Slice the array to get only the posts for the current page
  const paginatedPosts = markdownPosts.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

  const posts = paginatedPosts.map((fileName) => {
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(`${path}/${fileName}`, "utf8");
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);
    return {
      slug: fileName.replace(".md", ""),
      data: matterResult.data,
    };
  });

  return posts;
};
export default getPostMetadata
```

My list of blog pages is in this structure: app/blog/[page].tsx and the component looks like this:

```js
// app/blog/[page].tsx

import React from "react";
import getPostMetadata from "@/components/ReusableComponents/createPaginationMetaData";
import { PostMetadata } from "@/components/ReusableComponents/PostMetadata";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = getPostMetadata("blog", 1
  , Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / 10); // Assuming 10 posts per page

  const params = Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, index) => ({
    params: { page: `${index + 1}` },
  }));

  return params;
}

export async function load({ params }: any) {
  const currentPage = parseInt(params.page, 10) || 1;
  const postsPerPage = 10; // Assuming 10 posts per page
  const posts = getPostMetadata("blog", currentPage, postsPerPage);

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      currentPage,
      totalPages: Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage),
    },
  };
}

export default function BlogList({ posts, currentPage, totalPages }: { posts: PostMetadata[], currentPage: number, totalPages: number }) {
  const postPreviews = posts.map((post) => (
    <div key={post.slug}>{post.data.article_body.content.heading.t_title}</div>
  ));

  // Create pagination controls
  const paginationControls = (
    <div>
      {currentPage > 1 && <a href={`/blog/${currentPage - 1}`}>Previous</a>}
      {currentPage < totalPages && <a href={`/blog/${currentPage + 1}`}>Next</a>}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <>
      {postPreviews}
      {paginationControls}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: There are too many ways of pagination implementation. if you show what you have done and what went wrong, you can get help on your specific pagination implementation.

Comment: @Yilmaz Hi I updated the code. I tried using generateStaticParams since nextjs doesn't let you use getStaticProps and getStaticPaths for app directories. I don't know why it still doesn't work here.

Comment: If you're implementing SSG, you wouldn't paginate the results of your `getPostMetadata` function. Next.js needs to know ALL the posts at build time and create a static page for each post. You would then create a post index page that has some sort of search function or infinite scroll. You would handle all that on the client though. If you generate static params for the index page, then Next will pull the JSON from the server, but that JSON is statically generated in advanced, so you need to filter it client-side. Make sense?